# Updating version of dependency in package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

How to update version of a dependency which is required by other dependencies.

```
├─┬ vue-svgicon@3.2.9
│ └─┬ yargs@12.0.5
│   └── yargs-parser@11.1.1
```

In my case, yargs-parser needs to be updated to 13.1.1. Making any changes in the `package-lock.json` just overwrites it when you run `npm install`.

1. `npm audit fix` doesnt update it either

---

2. Tried doing with `npm-shrinkwrap.json` as an override for `package-lock.json` but want to find out some other alternative.

---

3. Another alternative is to do a define

```
"resolutions"
```

in the `package.json` file in addition to

```
"preinstall": "npm-force-resolutions"
```

but this adds an additional dependency of npm-force-resolutions which is not desired

Comment: What if `yargs@12.0.5` doesn't work with `yargs-parser@13.1.1`?

Comment: Is there any way to check the compatibility? is it possible to shed `yargs-parser` completely. its being brought in by other packages as well

Comment: You can check the `package.json` in `node_modules/yargs`